Density altitude difference (formula and Asa CX-3)
I am trying to figure out Density Altitude problem from the book and I get one answer by hand and another with CX-3 and cannot find the bug.
So problem goes like this,

Indicated Altitude    5250 feet
Baro  1010 hPa
OAT     27 C

I calculate,

Pa = ( ( 1013-1010 ) * 30 ) + 5250 = 90 + 5250 = 5340
Temperature = 15 - (2 * 5340 / 1000 ) = 4.32
Density Altitude in Feet = Pressure Altitude in Feet + (120 x (OAT°C –
ISA Temperature °C))
DA = 5340 + ( 120 * ( 27 - 4.32))
 5340 + ( 120 * 22.68 )

 5340 + 2721.6

 8061.6


At the same time my CX-3 calculator shows,

IAlt 5250 FT
Baro 1010 MB
PAlt 5339
OAT 27
DAlt 7890

Answer in the book says exactly that number.... but how did they calculate it, what I am doing wrong here?
Thank you all for helping out!

Bottom line is the formula (Density Altitude in Feet = Pressure Altitude in Feet + (120 x (OAT°C – ISA Temperature °C))) is an approximation to be used "in a pinch." Differences of about 200 feet (~2%) are fine, especially considering humidity differences may also effect density altitude by hundreds of feet. See the Pilot's Handbook of Aeronautical Knowledge, FAA-H-8083-25B, beginning on page 4-4, for more information and web sites.
P.S. you might want to check the pressure lapse rate in your Pa equation.
